# Scan QRCODE then send the decoded data and the smartphone's location to webserver

Tags: android

My goal is to scan a QRCODE with a smartphone, decode the data, then send the data and the phone's current location to an email address or to a website form for database storage.

I've found apps that can scan, decode, and email...but not retrieve location info..

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: google for how to get latitude and longitude in android.. there is location manager class for this purpose ..

Answer (score 1):

Use Android zxing library to scan QR code. I have used in multiple projects and its quite useful. Smartphone  location can easily be obtained via enabling GPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ZXing library to scan the QR code and use the OS' location APIs to get the location of the user.